# Google colaboratoryでseleniumのChromedriverが動かない。

Tags: python, python3, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory, chromedriver

Google colaboratory上でseleniumを動かそうとしていますが、
Chromedriver実行がうまくいきません。

**■やったこと**
１）chromedriverをcolabの”content”上にアップロード。
２）以下コマンドを叩く。

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys as keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/content/chromedriver")
```

**■エラーメッセージ**
`OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/content/chromedriver'`

**■参考にしたページ**
https://teratail.com/questions/66660
どうやら実行権限の問題らしいのですが、colab上でどのようにコマンドすれば良いのか検討がつきません。

※macOS, Chrome：80.0.3987.132, ChromeDriver：80.0.3987.106

ご教示いただけたら幸いです。

Comment: そのままGoogle検索をすると導入方法の記事がヒットするようですよ。https://qiita.com/ftoyoda/items/fe3e2fe9e962e01ac421

Comment: 他にもこんな記事があるようです。[Selenium on Colaboratory と時間制限回避手法に関するポエム](https://qiita.com/Ningensei848/items/a7daa6ee4ef692a3d65e), [google ColaboratoryでSeleniumを使う](https://enjoy-a-lot.com/google-colaboratory-selenium/), [PythonでGoogleColaboratoryを使ってスクレイピングする！コードそのまま！！](https://hirobeya.com/python%E3%81%A7googlecolaboratory%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%EF%BC%81%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%9D/), [COLABORATORYでスクレイピングする方法](https://itstudio.co/2019/01/25/8795/)

Comment: なるほど、「phantomjs」って言う手もあるんですね。kunifさんいつもありがとうございます。